# Calculating a matrix-exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

Let A be the following matrix.
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have to calculate $e^A$.

My idea was to diagonalize A because then $e^A = Pe^DP^-1$ if $A = PDP^-1$.

But A cannot be diagonalized since 1 is a double eigenvalue and therefore A does not have 2 linearly independent eigenvectors.

How else can I calculate $e^A$?

Thank you!

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079950/compute-the-n-th-power-of-triangular-3-times3-matrix) for some neat methods for computing $A^n$

Comment: Have you tried to compute $A^k$ ?

Comment: @JonasEGluch Hahaha nice if one see exaclty the same question in two forums;)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/747873/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014616/42969, all found quickly with a search for “matrix exponential” on this site.

Answer (score 7):

Note that $A^k = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

So $e^A = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}A^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & k \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k!} \\ 0 & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} e & e \\ 0 & e \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Please check for obvious duplicates before answering. This has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 5):

You can write : $A = I_2 + N$ with $N = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ nilpotent. Then, $N^2 = 0$ and $N$ commutes with $I_2$. So :

$$ A^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} I_2^{n-k} N^k = I_2 + n N $$

Therefore :

$$ e^A = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!} = I_2 \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} + N \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k!} = I_2 e + N e $$

This is a general strategy to compute the exponential even when the matrix is not diagonal.

Comment: Your statement, "But A cannot be diagonalized since 1 is a double eigenvalue and therefore A does not have 2 linearly independent eigenvectors."  is not, stricktly speaking true.  In this case, there are not two independent eigenvectors buy it is quite possible for a 2 by 2 matrix to have a double eigenvalue and have two independent eighenvectors.  An obvious [matirx]e\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & 1\end[/bmatrix] which has a1 as a double eigenvalue but but has both (1, 0) and 0, 1) as eigenvectors.

Comment: Please check for obvious duplicates before answering. This has been asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

I offer a third method for finding matrix exponentials, which is a popular technique in Electrical Engineering.

Given matrix is
$$
A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$

We find
$$
s I - A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
s - 1  & -1 \\
0 & s - 1 \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
where $s$ is a complex variable.

We find that
$$
(s I - A)^{-1} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
{1 \over s - 1} & {1 \over (s - 1)^2} \\[2mm]
0 & {1 \over s - 1} \\[2mm]
\end{array} \right]
$$

The inverse Laplace transform of $(s I - A)^{-1}$ is the state transition matrix, which is also the matrix exponential, $e^{A t}$.

Hence, we get
$$
e^{A t} = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[ (s I - A)^{-1} \right]
= \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( {1 \over s - 1} \right) &  \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( {1 \over (s - 1)^2} \right) \\[2mm]
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(0) &  \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( {1 \over s - 1} \right)  \\[2mm]
 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{t} & t e^t \\[2mm]
0 &   e^t \\[2mm]
 \end{array} \right]
$$

In particular, we get
$$
e^{A} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 e^{1} & 1 e^1 \\[2mm]
0 &   e^1 \\[2mm]
 \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 e  & e \\[2mm]
0 &   e\\[2mm]
 \end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: Please check for obvious duplicates before answering. This has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Dear Martin: We are allowed to give answers using different techniques. First two answers did not make use of Laplace transform technique.

Comment: The purpose of closing questions as a duplicate is to have all solutions to a problem at one place. If you have a new solution to a question that has been asked and answered before then the preferred approach is (as I understand it): Vote or flag  the question as a duplicate, and add another answer to the duplicate target.

Comment: Martin: First of all, I agree that this is a common problem in finding matrix exponentials. I saw a similar question but the matrix was the transpose of the matrix in this question and not the same. I answered only because the questions were not closed. I don't have powers to close questions - I am a new user here, thanks!

Comment: Flag -> a duplicate -> ...

Comment: OK noted - thanks!